# Removing unwanted attributes from spatial join using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am new to ArcGIS 10 and am currently building a model. This is a brief rundown of what I am doing at the moment.

I have 2 shapefiles: one a polyline and the other is point data.

I have joined both files using the spatial join tool within the model which created a shapefile that contains the attributes of both files. But I would like to get rid of the attributes obtained from the polyline and retain the attributes from the points since the shapefile has changed to a polyine.

Comment: Do you need to drop fields?

Comment: I think @Aaron is right - try deleting the unwanted fields using the [Delete Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004n000000) tool first - it's conceptually simpler than getting into Field Mappings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try incorporating [Delete Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004n000000) into your model.  You can easily drop multiple fields in this one step.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the `FieldMappings()` object. I use the `FieldMappings()` object programmatically through python. However the `FieldMappings()` object is available through the `SpatialJoin()` and `Merge()` tools when inserted into a custom model. I suggest start reading through the [FieldMappings() documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000008q000000) and then play around with it. It's a bit tricky to learn at first but once you understand how it works it becomes a very useful way to merge various types of geometry (or the same types of geometry) data while keeping (or dropping) fields and attributes.